# Open map url in iPhone simulator always redirects

Tags: iphone, maps

I have written an iPhone app that uses google maps for displaying maps.

I.e.

http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=48.85812229675187,2.294490337371826

with:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

But I always gets redirected to the current location. What am I doing wrong? How can I avoid this?

Comment: Maps in the simulator doesn't work the same way it does on the device.  I'm not sure how much trouble you want to go through to make it work the same on the simulator (since Apple didn't go through that trouble, either!)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=48.85812229675187,2.294490337371826
```

(notice the q instead of ll)

This lets Maps.app search for the specified location.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help. When I deployed the app to the iPhone everything worked though.